# How to remain in the same page on hover table

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I've got an hover table with several pages, each row has some action that one can perform with an item.
Whenever one of those actions is performed the page refreshes and the website comes back to page 1 of the table. Is there a way to remain in the same page where I last executed an action on a row?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, we will need to see your code in order to help. Please provide a brief but fully functional example of what you are doing and explain what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

I was already able to solve this problem, I was not being very precise in my google search and once I changed that I was able to find a pretty simple solution:

`$(document).ready(function(){
 $(#tableid).DataTable({
  stateSave:true
 });
});`